# Pros and Cons of the Tunturi R25 Magnetic Rowing Machine

Tags: exercise-equipment

I bought a new tunturi R25 rowing machine to replace one I had for years of the same make.

The new one is a magnetic rower, while the old one is a piston. [here](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?rlz=1C1CHFX_en-gbGB473GB473&q=tunturi%20rower&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=13503077795083744172&sa=X&ei=KjhzT46nBamp0QX2w_AT&ved=0CJ8BEPMCMAI) is the new one.

I got it and put it all together and I have three problems with it.

One - it may be thinner than my old one, but it's much chunkier. I used to stand the old one up and hide it behind a cupboard. This one does fold, but it's still quite big.

Two - I can't come as far forward on the new one as I could on the old one, on the old one I used to hunch up all the way to the front, this one I have to limit my motion a bit, although it's fine going back.

Three - The old one allowed you to set the clamp on the piston arms so that the resistance made it almost impossible to row. On the new one I'm already on the highest resistance setting and it's not very hard. It's OK, but no room for improvement. One thing I liked about the old rower was that as well as being good cardio, all these muscles started appearing on my back, so I kept turning up the resistance which was good until it broke...

Are these problems worth sending the thing back for? Or do they not matter?

and if they are legit problems, what's the alternative? All the piston ones are really cheap and people say they break, but the alternatives are huge! i don't want a giant piece of equipment in my house!

Comment: This a good question :) the FAQ says you can ask things about "gear and gadgets used during exercise".

Comment: I think my main gripe is - surely I should be able to replace my 15 year old piston rower with a new one that does everything the old one did and more for the same price? I find it annoying that the old one did some things better despite this costing more.

Answer (score 1):

After doing very extensive research it seems the right product just does not exist. Better rowers cost much more than the r25. A model that I'd be more than happy to get is the kettler kadett - it may not be quite as good as the r25 but it's smaller and well, I don't need a top if the range rower.

Oh wait, it's actually more expensive than the r25, but not as good - so that's out of the question. And all of the other small piston rowers don't provide enough resistance and aren't of a good enough build quality for someone that rows as much as I do.

The concept rower is the best but way too expensive. The only other option is the tunturi r60, but honestly I was really hoping to 'upgrade' to a more compact model.

I think I'll send the r25 back and fix the giant piece of iron I've used for years until something comes out.

Very disappointing.